# Command Python: Select Interpreter resulted in an error: Cannot destructure property 'filename' of 'r' as it is undefined

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I just ran into infinite *Discovering Python Interpreters*.

[image: Discovering Python Interpreters]

Then I tried almost everything, including deleting extensions, reloading VS Code, changing Python Path and etc.
But finally when I just tried to select the interpreter I came across the error:

> Command Python: Select Interpreter resulted in an error: Cannot destructure property 'filename' of 'r' as it is undefined

[image: Error]

However I have `PYTHONPATH` defined and `python3` works well in console.

P.S. Created issue on Github: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/21481

Comment: Find the setup of [vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial) here.

Comment: @Hermann12 interpreter selection doesn't work. VS Code setup is useless here!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be an issue of cache corruption. If you're able to run commands in the command palette, try running `Python: Clear cache and reload window`. Source: @karthiknadig's comment [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/21481#issuecomment-1608487074).

Answer (score 1):

I assume something with your setting is wrong:
[image]
I use the extension:
[image]
Selected Interpreter:
[image]
Bye the way, I use [Thonny](https://thonny.org/) :-)